# Reject by iTunes Connect by the reason "Your iTunes Connect settings indicate that your app serves third-party advertisements. "

Tags: ios, admob, app-store-connect

I tried to upload my app which uses Google AdMob interstitial. However, was rejected by this reason.

```
Your iTunes Connect settings indicate that your app serves third-party advertisements. However, we were unable to locate ads in your app. 

Please reply to this message to provide the steps for locating third-party ads in your app. When we hear back from you, we will continue the review.
```

Somebody know how I should reply? I used CocoaPods and installed the "Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK".

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Login to your iTunes Connect account and choose the app, you have uploaded, there will be a link to reply. In your reply specify the screen where you included the ad, and how you show it (Means delay, or any specific case something like that)

Comment: ^Should be an and the answer.

Comment: Thanks guys, I sent  the message and now waiting for a reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At time of uploading application on iTunes, you check for your app that app servers third-party apps. But, they are not able to find it. So, you can provide steps to navigate on screen where you displaying ads.

Comment: So sorry, I'm a beginner at this site and didn't know how to.

Comment: You can click on up arrow

Answer (score 0):

you should check the [IDFA options](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/IDFA_Page2-1.jpg?__hstc=222691652.72176e60a3b15c5c96f291502fddafc7.1436938024938.1436938024938.1436938024938.1&__hssc=222691652.3.1436938024939&__hsfp=710304778) on the app settings

Answer (score 0):

This is simple : you are displaying advertisements in your app (Google AdMob interstitial).

Most of the time, SDKs that are used for advertising, use the Advertising Identifier of the device, so that the ads can be more targeted for user.

Basically, when when submitting your app to itunes there is a step about **Advertising Identifier**

Check **Yes**, and it will make appear others elements to check that fits your app advertising use cases.

For exemple you have to check : "*Serve advertisements within the app*", and see yourself if the others apply to your app

[image]